# In python, how do I get list of objects contained in multiple lists

Tags: python, list

Using python 2.6 I have essentially a list of lists. Some objects are the same within one or more of the lists.

I need to get a list of objects that are contained in ALL of the lists.

For example:

```
list1 = ['apple','pear','cheese','grape'] 
list2 = ['grape','carrot','pear','cheese']
list3 = ['apple','cheese','grape']
```

The resulting list would need to be

```
['grape','cheese']
```

because they are the only objects in all 3 lists.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can learn Apriori Algorithm firstly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm

Comment: Step one would be writing some code.

Comment: You probably want to use the `set` builtin class. But keep in mind that sets only have unique items in them, where a list can have multiples of the "same" item. That means you have to be sure what you are really after.

Comment: Here is the Python documentation for sets and various set operations. I hope that this is a constructive and helpful comment. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter(list1+list2+list3)

print([x for x in a if a[x]==3])
```

Comment: `all()` is a built-in function, don't overwrite it. It will also only work if there are 3 lists and if each string appears in each list only once (the OP didn't mention that duplicates were not an issue).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `set` operator like this:

```
set(list1) & set(list2) & set(list3)
```

If you want a `list` as output you can do:

```
list(set(list1) & set(list2) & set(list3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

```
list1 = ['apple','pear','cheese','grape'] 
list2 = ['grape','carrot','pear','cheese']
list3 = ['apple','cheese','grape']

print(list(set(list1) & set(list2) & set(list3)))
```

Output:

```
['grape', 'cheese']
```

If you want the words to be sorted alphabetically you can also do this:

```
print(sorted(set(list1) & set(list2) & set(list3)))
```

Output:

```
['cheese', 'grape']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sets and set intersections:

```
>>> list1 = ['apple','pear','cheese','grape'] 
>>> list2 = ['grape','carrot','pear','cheese']
>>> list3 = ['apple','cheese','grape']
>>> list_of_lists = [list1,list2,list3]
>>> reduce(set.intersection,map(set,list_of_lists))
set(['cheese', 'grape'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Do use the `set` class, it has useful methods like `intersection` that can be used to manipulate like iterables like Euler sets.
Here is the proof of concept and the answer to your question:

```
list1 = ['apple', 'pear', 'cheese', 'grape'] 
list2 = ['grape', 'carrot', 'pear', 'cheese']
list3 = ['apple', 'cheese', 'grape']
print set(list1) & set(list2) & set(list3)
```

This will return a set object but if you want a list just use the `list()` method.

Hopefully you will be able to do something useful with it or probably learn something new.

You should read up on sets here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,8]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
c = [4,8,9]

print(list(set(a).intersection(b).intersection(c)))
```

I am using intersection() as it will add more readability in the code and other who is going to use this code will know what you are trying to do.